# autocomplete by ajax php mysql

Tags: php

**test.php**

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function callajax()
            {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        var customarray=new Array();
                        var str=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        customarray=str.split(",");
                        var obj = actb(document.getElementById('tb_name'),customarray);
                        alert(customarray[0]);
                    }
                }

                var username=document.getElementById('tb_name').value;

                xmlhttp.open("POST","fetchvalue.php",true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send("userid="+username);
            }   
        </script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="actb.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='' method='post'>
            <table> 
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="tb_name" onkeyup="callajax();" id='tb_name'/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
</script>
```

**fetchvalue.php**

```
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    if (!mysql_select_db($db, $link)) {
        echo 'Could not select database';
        exit;
    } 
    $uid=$_POST['userid'];
    //$uid='a';
    $select=mysql_query("select * from login where user LIKE '%$uid%'");
?>
<?php 
    while($f=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
        echo $f['user'].',';
    }
?>
```

its work fine but we have to use this `alert(customarray[0]);`

plz help me..

Answer (score 1):

I strongly discourage to use custom made solution when there are pretty good alternative already builted.

See jQuery UI autocomplete here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/